# Insert a function by "Verbatim", but not start a new line

Tags: verbatim

I want to insert a function using verbatim so that my code looks like in a good way (different than regular text). When I insert a function, I always start a new line. Could I insert the function just followed my text by not starting a new line? Thank you. 
PS: I want put the text "We call the function below via" and the function "tran.prob(N=5, q=0.5)" in the same line.

Here is my code:

```
We call the function below via 
\begin{verbatim}
tran.prob(N=5, q=0.5)
\end{verbatim}
```

Comment: Use `\verb|tran.prob(N=5, q=0.5)|`

Comment: I would even say: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) !

Comment: If you need the verbatim "conditioned" in any way (color, size, shape, etc.) other than what `\verb|tran.prob(N=5, q=0.5)|` yields, let me know.  There are other options for more fancy verbatim forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `\verb|tran.prob(N=5, q=0.5)|`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
We call the function below via \verb|tran.prob(N=5, q=0.5)|, which is inline.
\end{document}
```

[image: A screenshot]

Comment: Or simply `\texttt`

Comment: Yes, but `\texttt` would not work if the function was called `tran%prob`: `File ended while scanning use of \texttt .`

Comment: Just to point to a simpler solution that works in many cases.

Comment: I had no doubt that _you_ knew that `:-)`